# Consuming apex webservices on android

Tags: android, web-services, salesforce

Can any one guide me about the following

1. Login to apex webservice in salesforce using android
2. Accessing end point
3. Sending the request and recieving response

Answer (score 1):

Here's 2 good links that should help. Haven't done it myself but none the less looks like it'll answer what you want

http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Building_Android_Applications_with_the_Force.com_REST_API

and there's also a toolkit here:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_Android

Hope it helps